# Obtaining a SATA Disk Password from an RDX drive bay

Tags: hard-drive, password-protection, proprietary, drive-bay

I have a bunch of [RDX backup cartridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDX_Technology) and, given that they contain standard 2.5" SATA drives, I recently wanted to open them in order to be able to use the drives outside of the proprietary drive bay.

However, after connecting the drives directly via SATA to my PC, they did not show any content. It took me quite long, but I managed to find out that the drives reported as locked if checked with `hdparm`.

My assumption is that the proprietary drive bay controller simply protects them with a password, and that, after obtaining this password I should be able to use them normally.
I have the proprietary drive bay at hand and won't shy away from opening it, soldering on it or diving *a little* into microcontrolling, reverse engineering or whatever might be applicable here. The drive bay has a USB 3 connection and inside sits a Texas Instruments TUSB9261 USB-to-SATA controller. I believe the corresponding SPI chip would be the one labeled 2SPE20VP.

**I would be grateful for any advice on where to appropriately ask this question, what to do and how.**

Currently, I see the following options but don't know about their practicability or how to actually implement any of them:

1. Build something that poses to the bay as a regular drive, but
   instead records any attempts to unlock it with the secret passcode.
2. Attach a few wires on the SATA plug and sniff on the connection while the bay unlocks one of the drives with the right passcode.
3. Dump the USB controller firmware and reverse engineer it to find the passcode / how it is generated if isn't the same for each drive.
   Of course, this would likely be one hell of work, but if not, it
   maybe even adds the chance to modify the firmware so that in the future the bay could operate my disks without locking them?

Comment: have you tried that software (there are a few that can do this) Read / Write everything ? http://rweverything.com/

Answer (score 0):

RDX (RD1000) drives seem to use HIGH security, not MAX security, and there are reports their *master* password is blank.

So, provided **you are ready to lose all data on those drives** (can't harm to say it again), you can wipe the drives to unlocked status:

```
hdparm --user-master m --security-erase '' /dev/sda # SLOWLY WIPE CLEAN /dev/sda
```

I cannot assure you that *your* disks's master password is actually blank. It makes good sense (the disk remains useable, the data remain secure) but it's not God's law that the manufacturer ever believed in good sense. They might have gone for paranoid between those reports and your drives' manufacture date. I believe it's worth a shot, though.

There is also [this tool](http://www.hddoracle.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=166&p=334) which attempts to do the same. I haven't tested it, nor have I verified it's not, say, malware. Use appropriate caution.

Finally, on some drives there is a "recover a disk as a blank disk even if you lost the password" by using a special PSID master password that is printed on the disk label. Here, it is all zeroes, at the bottom of the label:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the blank password did not work, aswell as the option with 32 spaces that i found somewhere reported to be a possible master password for Toshiba drives.

Command output:
`$ sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-erase '' /dev/sdb
security_password: ""

/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="", user=master
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Comment: I have found a thread that seems germane. Apparently, you *can* read and partially rewrite back the disk firmware, thus setting a known *master* password, with which you can then erase the disk to an unlocked state. Some softwares are claimed to be able to do this (Victoria HDD boot for example, or this one for Windows: https://hdd-unlock-wizard.software.informer.com/4.2/ - I've found claims it works, and gripes it doesn't).

Comment: This other guy reports unlocking a Toshiba disk w/o password. A DOS boot disk is apparently required, as for Zu. https://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=32719